# How to apply data-target collapse for dynamic unique id with each associated button

Tags: python, html, css, bootstrap-4, django-templates

i am using the bootstrap-4 collapse in Django template, where i want the card should collapsed with associated buttons, where i am providing the unique id to data target that matches with the card collapse id, But its not working fine.Though all the elements are showing as it is multiple button with associated card.But card is not getting collapsed.

I have tried the simple variable name (ex:data-target = #demo, data-toggle = collapse ) and in the card i am providing the same id (id=demo class = collapse).

```
{% if translator.task_set.all %}
        {% for task in translator.task_set.all %}
        {% fetching_variable_id as variable_id %}
     <div id="myGroup">
    <h2>
          <button class="p-0" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{variable_id}}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
           {{ task.deadline }}
              {% admin_task_status_display task.id as status%}
              <div style="float:right;" class="ml-auto mr-3 m-1"><small>{{status.0}}</small></div>
          </button>
    </h2>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="collapses m-1" id="{{variable_id}}" data-parent="#myGroup">
            <div class="row">
                {% for task_card in task.cards.all %}
                  <div class="card m-2 ml-2" style="width: 15.5rem;">
                      <div class="card-body" style="text-align:justify;">
                        <h5 class="card-context" style="font-size:0.85rem; font-weight:bold;">{{ task_card.context }}</h5>
                        <p class="card-content" style="font-size:0.85rem;">{{ task_card.content }}</p>
                        <p class="card-cue" style="font-size:0.85rem;">{{ task_card.cue }}</p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                {% end for %}

            </div>

            <div class="row m-5">

              <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                <h5>Message</h5>
              </div>

              <div class=" col-sm-12 col-md-5" style="margin-left:1rem;">
                  <p><code style="color:black;">{{ task.message }}</code></p>
              </div>
            </div>

                {% if task.reminder_set.all %}
            <div class="row m-5">

              <div class=" col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <h5>Reminder</h5>

              </div>
            </div>
                {% for reminder in task.reminder_set.all %}
                    <p>{{ reminder.reminder }}</p>
                {% end for %}
                {% endif %}
            <form method="post">
                {% c s r f _token %}
                <input type="hidden" name="task_id" value="{{ task.id }}">
                <div class="row  m-3">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ form.reminder }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <button type="button">Remind</button>
                </div>

                </div>
            </form>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        {% end for %}
```

Comment: You are outputting `<div id="myGroup">` in a loop, so you are violating the rule that IDs must be unique within an HTML document right there already.

Comment: i have cleared that division still no response.

Comment: What do you mean you cleared it, if you still want to use data-parent, you can’t just get rid of it. Have you tried to compare the structure of the HTML you are dynamically creating here, with a static version that “works”? Any significant differences?

Comment: see i have discarded the data-parent attribute also. If i am using simple (id=something )it is working but if i click one button all the cards get collapsed irrespective of cards

Comment: What are you using as ID values? Are those numeric? If so, add a letter as a prefix, IDs starting with a digit can easily cause problems.

Comment: yeah it helps me.Now working fine.thank you